# Revit API - C# - How to put the focus a on a precise view

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to , when I click on a button in my Window, put the focus a on plan view. To do this, my click method use another method : SelectCoordinatesEvent (code below).
It is in this method that I will decide to focus on a plan view, just before calling my PickPointXYZ() method which is used to take the coordinates of an area on Revit.

Do you have any idea how to do that ? I precise that I am quite a beginner with Revit API.

Thanks a lot,
Hugo

```
public List<XYZ> PickPointXYZ(UIApplication uiapp)
        {
            XYZ pointXYZ;
            List<XYZ> pointsXYZ = new List<XYZ>();
            Selection sel = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Selection;

            ObjectSnapTypes snapTypes = ObjectSnapTypes.Endpoints;

            int nbOfSelectedPoints=0;

// I want to put the focus on the view at this moment, juste before the while loop that ask the user to select points on Revit.
//I precise that all my plane view have an Active Workplane set
            while (true)
            
            {
                try
                {
                    pointXYZ = sel.PickPoint(snapTypes, "Selectionnez les points formant le coutour de la zone de stockage."+"\r\n"+ "Une fois la sélection terminée, appuyez sur Echap.");
                    pointsXYZ.Add(pointXYZ);
                    nbOfSelectedPoints++;
                }
                catch(Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException e)
                {
                    if (nbOfSelectedPoints < 3)
                   
                    {
                        TaskDialog.Show("Erreur - Nombre de points selectionnés", "Vous avez selectionné moins de 3 points."+"\r\n"+"Veuillez supprimer la zone et recommencer la saisie.", TaskDialogCommonButtons.Close) ;
                    }
                        break;
                }
                catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    
                    TaskDialog.Show("Erreur - Vue selectionnée", "Vous avez selectionné une vue qui ne possède pas de Plan de Construction."+"\r\n"+"Veuillez supprimer la zone et recommencer la saisie dans une vue adaptée.", TaskDialogCommonButtons.Close);
                    break;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                    
                }
            }
            return pointsXYZ;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(int hwnd);

---

SetForegroundWindow(uiapp.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32());

---

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(int hwnd);

public List<XYZ> PickPointXYZ(UIApplication uiapp)
{

    SetForegroundWindow(uiapp.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32());

    XYZ pointXYZ;
    List<XYZ> pointsXYZ = new List<XYZ>();
    Selection sel = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Selection;

    ObjectSnapTypes snapTypes = ObjectSnapTypes.Endpoints;

    int nbOfSelectedPoints=0;

    // I want to put the focus on the view at this moment, juste before the while loop that ask the user to select points on Revit.
    //I precise that all my plane view have an Active Workplane set
    while (true)
    
    {
        try
        {
            pointXYZ = sel.PickPoint(snapTypes, "Selectionnez les points formant le coutour de la zone de stockage."+"\r\n"+ "Une fois la sélection terminée, appuyez sur Echap.");
            pointsXYZ.Add(pointXYZ);
            nbOfSelectedPoints++;
        }
        catch(Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            if (nbOfSelectedPoints < 3)
            
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("Erreur - Nombre de points selectionnés", "Vous avez selectionné moins de 3 points."+"\r\n"+"Veuillez supprimer la zone et recommencer la saisie.", TaskDialogCommonButtons.Close) ;
            }
                break;
        }
        catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            
            TaskDialog.Show("Erreur - Vue selectionnée", "Vous avez selectionné une vue qui ne possède pas de Plan de Construction."+"\r\n"+"Veuillez supprimer la zone et recommencer la saisie dans une vue adaptée.", TaskDialogCommonButtons.Close);
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
            
        }
    }
    return pointsXYZ;

}
```

Comment: Ok, this was the answer to myproblem but I Found another problem : When we hit the line :

pointsXYZ = sel.PickPoint(snapTypes, "Selectionnez les points formant le coutour de la zone de stockage."+"\r\n"+ "Une fois la sélection terminée, appuyez sur Echap.");

The Revit API PickPoint's method automaticcaly put the focus on my UI. What can I do to counter that ?

Comment: at the start of the command assign the value of uiapp.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() to a variable of type int and then change the line SetForegroundWindow (uiapp.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32());

for

SetForegroundWindow(VARIABLE_NAME);

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this code may be executing from a button click handler.  If so, you should use Revit's IExternalEventHandler instead.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2014/ENU/Revit/files/GUID-0A0D656E-5C44-49E8-A891-6C29F88E35C0-htm.html